# Analyzing Java PS Old Gen and possible memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Using Jmeter I'm running 1500 Transaction Per Second against a micro service built with Java Spring Boot and Cassandra back-end and I am suspecting a memory leak.

What would be the best way to analyze what the best way to see what is filling this memory?

PS Old Gen Current Capacity:
[image: PS Old Gen Current Capacity]

PS Old Gen Percentage of Maximum Capacity
[image: Percentage of Maximum Capacity]

Answer (score 1):

Dump the memory and analyze it with [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

use jmap to dump memory:

```
jmap –dump:format=b,file=<filename> <pid>
```

or let jvm dump itself when OOM happens by adding the following to java args:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<file-path>
```

Then use MAT to analyze the dumped file, MAT will show you the memory leak suspect, you can browse all the objects in the heap at the time of dumping, too.

There is also a much easier but less precise way to locate the objects consume most heap memory:

```
jmap -histo:live <pid>
```

This will print the memory cost of all living objects, aggregated by class. But with this method it is hard to pinpoint the problem. I recommend to use MAT.